# Way to equally size children elements in remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to define a container for couple of elements, which i would like to take equal height, so for example for 4 elements it's 25% of left space.

Also, at the bottom I need to have another element, which should be taken into account.

Below is an example of what i would like to achieve:

```css
.footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
}

.innerContainer {
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='innerContainer'>
    <p>This should take equal height (full height of parent equally splitted)</p>
    <p>This should take equal height (full height of parent equally splitted)</p>
  </div>
  <p class="footer">Outer Paragraph, which takes only needed space</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can add the following style to let your paragraphs take all the available space (note that the parent, as you wrote, has `flex-direction: column;`)

```
.innerContainer>p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If you want to be more generic you can also use `*`, for exampe if you want to mix `<p>`s and `<span>`s as childrens of `.innerContainer`

```
.innerContainer>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```